# clicking submit button proceeds to next event or action in java

Tags: java, jbutton

What I'm trying to do here is I'm trying to create a quiz like game where the user guesses who is in the picture. And would want it if whenever I clicked the submit button and the user correctly guesses the picture. It should proceed to the next question. I have tried using arrays but I have no idea where to put the syntax. and I am confused. also, I have tried using polymorphism. but everytime I clicked the submit button. the next picture shows up but the score and mistakes will disappear. -_-

Here is my code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Second extends JFrame{

    private int number, score;
    private String answer;
    private String[] answers;
    private ImageIcon[] questions;

    private JLabel lblQuestion, lblMistakes, lblScore;
    private JButton btnSubmit;
    private SubmitButtonHandler sbhandler;
    private JTextField txtAnswer;

    public Second(){

        setTitle("Guess Who");

        btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
        sbhandler = new SubmitButtonHandler();
        btnSubmit.addActionListener(sbhandler);

        txtAnswer = new JTextField(20);
        txtAnswer.setFont(new Font("Tekton Pro Ext", Font.BOLD, 20));
        txtAnswer.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

        lblMistakes = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
        lblMistakes.setForeground(Color.blue);
        lblMistakes.setFont(new Font("Tekton Pro Ext", Font.BOLD, 30));
        lblMistakes.setOpaque(true);

        lblScore = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
        lblScore.setForeground(Color.white);
        lblScore.setBackground(Color.black);
        lblScore.setFont(new Font("Tekton Pro Ext", Font.BOLD, 30));
        lblScore.setOpaque(true);

        questions = new ImageIcon[10];

        questions[1] = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\ACER\\Desktop\\mario.jpeg");
        questions[2] = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\ACER\\Desktop\\ss.jpg");
        questions[3] = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\ACER\\Desktop\\dora.jpg");
        questions[4] = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\ACER\\Desktop\\vegeta.jpg");
        questions[5] = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\ACER\\Desktop\\kirby.jpg");

        lblQuestion = new JLabel(questions[1]);
        lblQuestion.setFont(new Font("Tekton Pro Ext", Font.BOLD, 18));

        Container pane = getContentPane();

        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));

        pane.add(lblQuestion);
        pane.add(txtAnswer);
        pane.add(btnSubmit);
        pane.add(lblScore);
        pane.add(lblMistakes);

        setBounds(500,200,500,500);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }

private class SubmitButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        answers = new String[10];

        answers[1] = "Mario";
        answers[2] = "Spongebob Squarepants";
        answers[3] = "Dora the Explorer";
        answers[4] = "Vegeta";
        answers[5] = "Kirby";

        if(txtAnswer.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(answers[1])){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You got the correct answer.");
            number = number;
            score = score + 1;
            lblScore.setText("Score: " + Integer.toString(score));
            txtAnswer.setText("");
            txtAnswer.requestFocusInWindow();

        }else{
            number = number + 1;
            lblMistakes.setText("Mistakes: " + Integer.toString(number));
            txtAnswer.setText("");

            if(number == 1){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Try again.");
                lblMistakes.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                txtAnswer.requestFocusInWindow();
            }else if(number == 2){
                lblMistakes.setBackground(Color.orange);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Careful. You only have one chance.");
                txtAnswer.requestFocusInWindow();
            }else if(number == 3){
                lblMistakes.setBackground(Color.red);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Game Over.");
                dispose();
                Second s = new Second();
            }

        }
        }

    }


public static void main(String[]args){

    Second s = new Second();


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the names in the `actionPerformed` method but better to move them to an `init()` method. Also an `ArrayList` will provide you with more flexibilty than an array of fixed size. As an added bonus, you can use `Collections.shuffle()` to pick a random user for the next guess.

The score and mistakes are disappearing as you are creating a new `Second` object once the game is over. Better to reuse the instance you already have and hide/show components as necessary.

Comment: hmmm... i actually got used in using the constructor as to where i put the codes and stuff. using ArrayList will be new to me. initializing stuff is kind of not that big of a deal. but yes, i'll try cleaning my program. :) also, i've tried using for loop. but then again i don't know where to put. i try to put it at the button but even if i get the correct answer. it reads or continues to me else statements.

Comment: i kind of experimented my program. and actually got something out of it. but. during my experimentation i used a String question instead of an image question. and it actually worked. maybe the problem to my program is that the frame or the label needs to be refreshed in order for the new image to appear. i have tried using the repaint() method. but still nothing is happening. i also tried the dispose() and then call again the object but still nothing happened.